# KeyEvent Handler help - JAVA

Tags: java, keyevent

i'm trying to block the user from being able to type anything into a JTextField besides numbers, period (for decimal inputs), and backspace.

However, the code I came up with still blocks out the period and it "beeps" on every key press.

Here is the code:

```
private void SideLengthJTextFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                              
            //neglect any keys besides backspace, delete, period, digits

    char keyTyped = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!(Character.isDigit(keyTyped)) || (keyTyped == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) 
            || (keyTyped == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)
            || (keyTyped == KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD)
            || (keyTyped == KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL))//works for numpad period
    {
        evt.consume(); //Neglect any invadid keys
        getToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so, if you'd done some more research into the problem, eventually you would have found that `KeyListener` is NOT how this should be done - since Java 1.3, it's NOT the way this should be done.  Instead, you should be using a `DocumentFilter`

Comment: I'd also recommend that you have a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more details

Comment: OK, I am very new to this language have been using only for a couple weeks. I tried doing research but its very hard when you have no idea what you're looking for. Thanks, for the tip though.

Comment: Knowing what to search for is about 50% of developers skill set ;)

Comment: Well are there any errors with my current code? I'm just confused on why it wouldn't work...

Comment: Also, I don't understand how using a document filter would help me. All I'm trying to do is make it so only positive decimal numbers can be entered into a J Text Field.

Comment: KeyTyped may not be returning the actual char, I know at least one of KeyListener events doesn’t, just not which one off my head. DocumentFilter sits between the input and the underlying Document, allowing you to veto (or filter out) unwanted content before it reaches the Document. It covers the use cases where the user types text, pasted text or the field is updated by the program, which KeyListener only covers the first. Also, there’s no guarantee that the KeyListener will be notified before the Document is updated